# How I can have only link body copied?

Tags: redactor

For example, if link is `< a href ...> stuff </a>`, so that you copy it in textfield, only string 'stuff' is copied and nothing more?

When I copy some page with links in text in redactor editor, it copies links AS links, I want only string (link name, string inside link tag) be copied, and nothing more

Comment: Are you trying to avoid the formatting when you paste? If so, you can just use `ctrl` `shift` `v` instead of `ctrl` `v`... Not sure 100% what you're asking though.

Comment: @brbcoding, does tag 'redactor' matches redactor js - rich text editor? When I copy some page with links in text in redactor editor, it copies links AS links, I want  only string (link name, string inside link tag) be copied, and nothing more

Answer (score 2):

Have you test to add `HREF LINK` in `deniedTags` like this:

```
jQuery('#redactor').redactor({
   deniedTags: ['a']
});
```

[Reference](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/)

Answer (score 0):

In redactor 9.1.1 use setting [pastePlainText](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/#set-pastePlainText)

This setting allows users to have all html tags stripped from the pasted text. Generally it is "paste as plain text" feature.

Default setting is false, to turn on, set the following:

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
    pastePlainText: true
});
```